# Background pages for Chrome Extensions - totally unique?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

My question is simple - *persistent* background pages/scripts for Chrome Extensions - is there only one background script for all Chrome windows? Or is there a different instance of a background script for each Chrome window?

I am hoping that the background script is absolutely unique, such that there is only one instance no matter what, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's only `one` instance of background page per extension.

But, there is one exception: if your extension uses incognito "split" mode, the second instance of background page is created for incognito windows.

Official documentation [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

Comment: ok cool thanks, can I prevent split mode? how do I prevent that?

Comment: You cannot prevent that. However, you can avoid run of your background page script in incognito mode. You can use [`isAllowedIncognitoAccess`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-isAllowedIncognitoAccess) to detect it incognito mode or no.